# Add hours/minutes to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having an issue on how to add the Offset to the EventDateTime. Is there a way to do this? I would convert it to a decimal number but cannot because 5:30 is not 5.3 hours, it's 5 hours and 30 minutes.

The data is shown below with the expected output. Please help if possible.

Sample Data:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| EventDate | EventTime |    EventDateTime    |        TimeZone         | Offset |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 10/1/2020 | 5:00 PM   | 2020-10-01 5:00 PM  | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  |
| 10/1/2020 | 8:00 PM   | 2020-10-01 8:00 PM  | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  |
| 10/2/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-02 10:00 AM | UTC -4 EDT New York     | -4     |
| 10/2/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-02 10:00 AM | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     |
| 10/2/2020 | 2:00 PM   | 2020-10-02 2:00 PM  | UTC +1 BST London       | 1      |
| 10/2/2020 | 3:00 PM   | 2020-10-02 3:00 PM  | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     |
| 10/2/2020 | 8:00 AM   | 2020-10-02 8:00 AM  | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     |
| 10/5/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-05 10:00 AM | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  |
| 10/5/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-05 10:00 AM | UTC -5 CDT Chicago      | -5     |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Expected Outcome:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| EventDate | EventTime |    EventDateTime    |        TimeZone         | Offset |     UTCDateTime     |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| 10/1/2020 | 5:00 PM   | 2020-10-01 5:00 PM  | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  | 2020-10-01 10:30 PM |
| 10/1/2020 | 8:00 PM   | 2020-10-01 8:00 PM  | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  | 2020-10-02 1:30 AM  |
| 10/2/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-02 10:00 AM | UTC -4 EDT New York     | -4     | 2020-10-02 6:00 AM  |
| 10/2/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-02 10:00 AM | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     | 2020-10-02 3:00 AM  |
| 10/2/2020 | 2:00 PM   | 2020-10-02 2:00 PM  | UTC +1 BST London       | 1      | 2020-10-02 3:00 PM  |
| 10/2/2020 | 3:00 PM   | 2020-10-02 3:00 PM  | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     | 2020-10-02 8:00 AM  |
| 10/2/2020 | 8:00 AM   | 2020-10-02 8:00 AM  | UTC -7 PDT Los Angeles  | -7     | 2020-10-02 1:00 AM  |
| 10/5/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-05 10:00 AM | UTC +5:30 IST New Delhi | +5:30  | 2020-10-05 3:30 PM  |
| 10/5/2020 | 10:00 AM  | 2020-10-05 10:00 AM | UTC -5 CDT Chicago      | -5     | 2020-10-05 5:00 AM  |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

What I have done so far:

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Why are you storing a date and time value as a `varchar` in the first place? That's the *real* problem. Fix your design and you don't have this issue. A date and type data type is a binary value; it's up to the presentation layer how it's displayed, not the RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu The data was imported into the DB like this.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text (and DDL+DML for sample data). You still need to show us your expected results and attempt.

Comment: *"The data was imported into the DB like this"* that doesn't explain the design choice. The decision to create the column as a `varchar` had nothing but do with the import process.

Comment: @Larnu I have converted the date and time to it's respective format. Now I am trying to figure out how to add the offset to the time.

Comment: @DaleK I have reformatted the text and added the expected results.

Comment: @Dee and what have you tried? You can manipulate the string and convert to a datetime... give it a go and see where you get stuck. And if you add your sample data as DDL+DML it make it much easier for someone to copy out and test with.

Comment: @DaleK So I figured out how to convert the string to datetime. Now I'm trying to figure out how to add/subtract the Offset to the datetime. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Once your fix your data, and get it into a `datetimeoffset` you can use `AT TIME ZONE`.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not familiar with the datetimeoffset nor the AT TIME ZONE.

Comment: @DaleK the only thing I got so far was to convert the date and time into datetime. Other than that, I'm stuck trying to find a way to add/subtract the offset from the DateTime.

Comment: Sorry, @DaleK :) gotcha.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with the datetimeoffset nor the AT TIME ZONE" - thats what the documentation is for.

Comment: Even if you wanted to store the offset separately instead of in a `datetimeoffset`, you could still use `numeric` you just need to calculate say how much 30 minutes is of an hour, so `5:30` becomes `5.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly pretty, but it works...

```
DECLARE @eventDateTime VARCHAR(50), @offset varchar(10)

SET @eventDateTime = '2020-09-30 5:00AM'
SET @offset = '-5:30'

SELECT CASE WHEN @offset LIKE '-%' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,@eventDateTime) - REPLACE(@offset,'-','')
        ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,@eventDateTime) + REPLACE(@offset,'+','')
        END
```

Comment: If the offset was a single digit, I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `EventDateTime` and `Offset` columns to build a string which you can convert to a `datetimeoffset`. Then you can convert to a `datetime2` and add the offset on to get the UTC datetime.

```
declare @Test table (EventDateTime varchar(32), Offset varchar(32));

insert into @Test (EventDateTime, Offset)
values
('2020-10-01 5:00 PM', '+5:30');

select dateadd(minute, datepart(tzoffset, EventDateTimeOffset), convert(datetime2(0), EventDateTimeOffset)) [UTCDateTime]
from @Test
outer apply (values (convert(datetimeoffset, EventDateTime + ' ' + Offset))) X (EventDateTimeOffset);
```

Returns

| UTCDateTime |
| --- |
| 2020-10-01 22:30:00 |

Obviously correcting your data storage types is a better solution.